# Comparing SAS and R results after resolving a system of differential equations

Tags: r, sas, differential-equations

I my main objectif is to obtain the same results on SAS and on R. Somethimes and depending on the case, it is very easy. Otherwise it is difficult, specially when we want to compute something more complicated than the usual.

So, in ored to understand my case, I have the following differential equation system :

y' = z

z' = b* y'+c*y

Let :
b = - 2 , c = - 4, y(0) = 0 and z(0) = 1

In order to resolve this system, in SAS we use the command `PROC MODEL` :

```
 data t; 
    do time=0 to 40; 
    output; 
    end; 
 run; 

 proc model data=t ;
   dependent y 0 z 1;
   parm b -2 c -4;
     dert.y = z;
     dert.z = b * dert.y + c * y;
   solve y z / dynamic solveprint out=out1;    
 run;
```

In R, we could write the following solution using the `lsoda` function of the `deSolve` package:

```
library(deSolve)
b <- -2;
c <- -4;
rigidode <- function(t, y, parms) {
with(as.list(y), {
dert.y <- z
dert.z <- b * dert.y + c * y
list(c(dert.y, dert.z))
})
}
yini <- c(y = 0, z = 1)
times <- seq(from=0,to=40,by=1)
out_ode <- ode (times = times, y = yini, func = rigidode, parms = NULL)
out_lsoda <- lsoda (times = times, y = yini, func = rigidode, parms = NULL)
```

Here are the results :
SAS
[image]

R
[image]

For time t=0,..,10 , we obtain similar results. But for t=10,...,40, we start to have differences. For me, these differences are important.

In order to correct these differences, I fixed on R the error truncation term on 1E-9 in stead of 1E-6. I also verified if the numerical integration methods and the hypothesis  used by default are the same.

Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem?

Sincerely yours,
Mily

Comment: This is a very interesting problem indeed! Can you also output the iteration errors with the `itprint` option and compare the R equivalent?

Comment: Yes I will do it. :)